# jQuery - rebind datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use jQuery ajax. I have created function: `getDatalist()`. This function displays a table with data. I use this function on multiple places on your page. When you make a change in one table, I would like to see change in others. How to rebind all the tables? Is it a trick?

```
getDatalist: function(dataid)
    {
        $.post('ActionScripts/Load.php',{
        }, function(data) {
            $(dataid).html(data);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Are you looking for sth like `each()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ ? In case not, could you clarify your question?

Comment: Please clarify this phrase : "make a change in one table".

Comment: This function is displayed using 3 tables. And do I edit the first table. I want to make changes in others. How can I do?

Comment: what do you mean by edit? add some elements, write something in a textarea? you could look into http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/ and http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have all table ids or classes you can use each.

```
 var ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]


    getDatalist: function(dataid)
        {
            $.post('ActionScripts/Load.php',{
            }, function(data) {
              $.each(ids,function(index, value){
              $("#"+value).html(data);
    })
// or u can give same class name table then find and re insert them.
//for same class usage
//$(".commonTable").each(function(){
//$(this).html(data);
//})

            });
        }
```